# Only fire function when user is done typing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172816/how-can-i-call-a-function-after-a-person-stops-typing) post that talks about how to fire a function once the user is done typing. How can this be implemented in an aura component? This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
<aura:component controller="SearchController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="searchValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="articles" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="timer" type="Object"/>

                <span onkeyup="{!c.onKeyUpHandler}" onkeydown="{!c.onKeyDownHandler}">
                    <lightning:input aura:id="searchValue" 
                                     type="search" 
                                     placeholder="Enter text..." 
                                     class="fl sidenav-search"/>
                </span>

</aura:component>
```

component.js

```
onKeyUpHandler:function(component, event, helper) {
    let timer = component.get("v.timer");
    timer = setTimeout(helper.handleSearch(component,event,helper), 1000) 

    component.set("v.timer", timer);
},
onKeyDownHandler:function(component) {
    let timer = component.get("v.timer");
    clearTimeout(timer);

    component.set("v.timer", timer);
}
```

Comment: My helper function that calls apex gets called each keystroke. No errors. Functionality still works. I’m not sure how to debug it cause I don’t fully understand the solution from the link I shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you want to set a callback, you need to bind to a function. Assuming you also want to be in the Aura life cycle (which is almost always yes), the resulting Aura version of the code looks like this:

```
onKeyUpHandler:function(component, event, helper) {
    let timer = setTimeout(
      $A.getCallback(
        helper.handleSearch.bind(helper,component,event,helper)
    ), 1000) 
    component.set("v.timer", timer);
},
onKeyDownHandler:function(component) {
    let timer = component.get("v.timer");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    component.set("v.timer", null);
}
```

Notable changes:

- `v.timer` is set to null after clearing the timer.
- `v.timer` is not read before setting it via setTimeout.
- `$A.getCallback` ensures you're in an Aura life cycle event.
- `.bind(helper, component, event, helper)` returns a bound function reference with `this` set to `helper` (the same behavior as if you'd called it directly). Without this, the original code was calling the method immediately instead of waiting 1,000 ms.

Comment: That's for your efforts. I implemented what you suggested, and I do get a delay, but the function still fires multiple times after a few seconds: https://imgur.com/a/erTHXYI

Comment: The behavior I want: say the user types their name, there is a 2 second buffer after they finish typing their name. If they start typing their last name 1 second after finishing their first name, the search function does not fire. Once they've stopped typing for 2 seconds, then the function fires.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71557/delay-query-while-user-is-typing-in-lightning-component-search-bar?rq=1

Comment: I probably implemented yours wrong. The solution I found is a little different from yours, but I'm not one to judge cause I'm not a JavaScript expert.

Comment: @TylerZika It may be some kind of race condition, or possibly another bug. I'll do some research on this. I do know that if you were to press multiple keys at once, then release them, you'd get multiple events (keydown->keydown->keyup->keyup would fire two events). A more proper solution would also delete any previous timer in the keyup handler before setting a new one. This answer was more of a "port" of the original code from the other answer, which also has this problem.

Comment: thank regardless. I posted what worked for me that I found in the link I shared previously.

Comment: @sfdcfox In your code, bind function is returning a function with this set to "helper" but your explanation says, this is set to "component".

Comment: @javanoob Whoops, yeah, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I don't even need the `onKeyDownHandler` anymore.

```
onKeyUpHandler:function(component, event, helper) {
    var timer = component.get('v.timer');
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        var newlst = [];
        helper.handleSearch(component,event,helper);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        component.set('v.timer', null);
    }, 700);

    component.set('v.timer', timer);
},
```

and the helper is important. The `utility.getDataParams` is just a function from a static resource that I've generalized to enqueue server side apex for data retrieval.

```
handleSearch : function(component, event, helper) {
    let searchValue = component.find("searchValue").get("v.value");

    if(searchValue.length > 1) {
        this.searchForArticles(component, searchValue);
    } else {
        component.set("v.articles", []);                      
    }
},   
searchForArticles : function(component, searchValue) {
    let params = {searchValue:searchValue}
    //var d = new Date();
    //console.log(params);
    //console.log(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds());

    $A.getCallback(function() {
        utility.getDataParams(component, "c.getArticles", params, $A.getCallback(function(error, value) {
            console.log(value);
            component.set("v.articles", value);                      
        })); 
    })();

},
```